# Preventing Registry.GetValue overflow

Tags: c#, registry, dwm

I'm trying to get the DWM *colorizationColor* using:
    `Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM").GetValue("ColorizationColor")`

however it is returning **-2144154163** (the real value is *2150813133*)

I thinks this is because the value cannot be hold on a 32-bit int... however event casting (or Converting) to int64 fails.

*PD: It may sound like an easy question to answer but I cannot find a solution :(*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color values are pretty impractical as int values, it is best to convert it quickly.  A little wrapper to dispose the key doesn't hurt either:

```
using System.Drawing;
...
        public static Color GetDwmColorizationColor() {
            using (var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM")) {
                return Color.FromArgb((int)key.GetValue("ColorizationColor"));
            }
        }
```

But don't do it this way, there's a documented API for it.  P/Invoke DwmGetColorizationColor() to get the value, you'll get guaranteed compatibility behavior.  Important if some future Windows version changes this registry details.  Visit pinvoke.net for the declaration.

Comment: wow, it is exactly but i was looking for, thanks for the advice anyway, however is was using this because of http://www.withinwindows.com/2010/07/01/retrieving-aero-glass-base-color-for-opaque-surface-rendering/ the value can change depending whether transpareceny is enabled or not

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560890/vista-7-how-to-get-glass-color for detailed examples showing `DwmGetColorizationColor` doesn't work as advertised.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make an unchecked cast:

```
unchecked {
    value = (uint)intValue;
}
```

**EDIT**: `Registry.GetValue` returns an `object` containing a boxed `Int32` value.
[You cannot unbox the value and cast to a different value type in a single cast](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/).

When casting directly from object, you need to first unbox it to its actual type, then cast it to `uint`:

```
unchecked {
    value = (uint)(int)boxedObject;
}
```

Comment: @Luffy: See my edit, and see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx