# How do I retrieve the theme colour of Windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I would like to have a way to get the theme colour of the users Windows theme with WPF or C# code-behind. And with this colour I mean the one that can be set in *Personalization\Window Color and Appearance* under Windows 7(and Vista too, I think). I want to use this colour to make a gradient in much the same way as Trillian 5 does it.
[image]

I tried to find it myself, but unfortunately I'm not getting anywhere. Apparently it's not under `SystemColors.Whatever`. I have found something on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.themes.themecolor.aspx) but I can't figure out how to use it, nor do I think it's what I want.

If anyone could help me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `DwmGetColorizationColor` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969513.aspx) is what you're looking for; you'll need to P/Invoke.

Comment: Will this provide the color scheme only, or the Glass effect also?

Comment: It will provide the glass color selected in the personalization dialog.  You may need to rearrange the order though according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560890/vista-7-how-to-get-glass-color/3560931#3560931

Comment: Wow. I upvoted and faved that question ages ago and completely forgot about it...

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was looking for. Although a somewhat nicer implementation is preferable, this works just fine. The `ColorizationColor` returns a uint of an hexadecimal, converting that to AARRGGBB values gave me what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

The theme you see on Windows is based on **Glass**. You have to use a glass in your application to get the same effect.

Comment: Well i hoped you had some reference