# How can I get the system's glass color?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, colors, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vista/7: How to get glass color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560890/vista-7-how-to-get-glass-color)

Since Windows Vista it is possible to customize the System color:
[image: Color Customization]
 

How can I programatically get the currently set system color as ARGB or HEX value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the color of the glass you could have a look at either of these posts:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5262555/340045

or

[Vista/7: How to get glass color?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3560890/340045)

Comment: nope, i only need to read the currently set system color of the title bars to set the color of my control equal to the system color.

Comment: i don´t need the glass itself, I only need the color set in the system

Comment: @Paedow ok - does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5262555/340045

Comment: Yeah, that´s what I wanted...

Comment: -1 this not answer the question. this question is not about non client drawing.

Comment: @RRUZ the question got edited after I answered - I will update my answer with the link in the comment.