# WPF: How set active titlebar color to window background?

Tags: wpf, colors, background, titlebar, brushes

I have a WPF window without Titlebar and border. So I want change windows background based on it is active or not.

I writed code below but I got message `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Brush' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'`.

Can you help me how to do this? Thank you!

```
    // This function used for both "Actived" and "Deactived" event
    private void window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Background = (IsActive)? System.Drawing.SystemBrushes.ActiveCaption :
            System.Drawing.SystemBrushes.InactiveCaption;
    }
```

**EDIT**
Current my windows title bar have Lime color if it active, and gray if inactive, but other user may be diffrent. How can I get these color by code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `WPF`, instead of using the `System.Drawing.SystemBrushes` class you should use the [System.Windows.SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx) class. The brushes from the `System.Drawing` namespace are not directly compatible with the `System.Windows.Media` namespace brushes.

```
Background = (IsActive)? System.Windows.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrush :
            System.Windows.SystemColors.InactiveCaptionBrush;
```

If you want to use this in your `XAML`, you can use

```
Background="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrush}"
```

**Edit based on updated question**

If you want to get the theme colour in use, you'll have to use PInvoke. The native method is [DwmGetColorizationColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969513.aspx). This will return an integer so you can then create a `SolidColorBrush` with that integer and assign it to your background.

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern void DwmGetColorizationColor(out int pcrColorization, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]out bool pfOpaqueBlend);

int col;
bool opac;
DwmGetColorizationColor(out col, out opac);

//convert the int to a colour
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(col);
Color color = Color.FromRgb(bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);

Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
```

That should get your Lime green color.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. The color I get is default active/inactive color. Current my windows title bar have Lime color if it active, and gray if inactive. How can I get these color?

Comment: @TuyenTk - I've updated the answer. It should get your lime green colour. Does the `InactiveCaptionBrush` in the first answer not get the correct gray colour?

Comment: What about `bool opac`. I don't get the exact same color as the window active frame color but close, slightly burned.

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole - This thread my help with the opacity aspect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560890/vista-7-how-to-get-glass-color

Comment: thansk mannnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn...it was really helpful.