# How to get the active window title color brush on Windows 8.1?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

I'm trying to get a brush with the system color of an active window, or this blue color off my Windows 8.1 for example:

[image]

So I do this:

```
HANDLE hBrush = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION);
```

But the color that brush gives me is this:

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `GetThemeSysColorBrush`, and in general look at Visual Styles API

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thanks. But what am I supposed to pass as the 1st parameter, or `hTheme`? If I pass `NULL` then it returns NULL as well.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Hmm, guys. I'm not sure I understand how it works. I just tried `OpenThemeData(hWnd, L"window");` and then `TMT_ACTIVECAPTION` for `iColorID` but it gave me just a gray color. Moreover none of other flags gave me this expected blue as I showed above.

Comment: Try `L"Globals"` and also read AeroStyle.xml as per docs

Comment: I don't think any theme handles will get GetThemeSysColorBrush to return sensible values. Only GetThemeSysColor seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with "`0xA`" or "`COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER`" as documented in GetSysColor Function at MSND: [GetSysColor Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
HANDLE hBrush = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER);
```

Comment: `COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER` has a value of `10`, not `0x10`.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly,
[DwmGetColorizationColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969513(v=vs.85).aspx)  return this color value.

On Windows 7/Vista, it sounds like the situation was much more complicated due to the glass translucency effects:
[Vista/7: How to get glass color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560890/vista-7-how-to-get-glass-color)

Since you're dealing with Windows 8.1, transparency is disabled, so this should provide the opaque color for the Window.